# multidimensional array for jqplot chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl, jqplot

I am trying to create Jqplot  bar charts and facing difficulty in creating multidimensional array in like

```
   var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [
    [[2,1], [4,2], [6,3], [3,4]], 
    [[5,1], [1,2], [3,3], [4,4]], 
    [[4,1], [7,2], [1,3], [2,4]]],
```

My data is in a HashMap inside hashMap it is like

```
 {software={low=1,high=5, medium=4}, harware={low=3,high=3},network{low=3,high=3,medium=8}}
```

How I can interpret my data in above multidimensional array.

I have written the following code to achieve this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    <c:forEach var="data" varStatus="main" items="${data}">  

    var cdata = new Array();

    var twoDOuterArray = new Array(${data.size()});

    <c:forEach var="mapEntry" varStatus="status" items="${data['cData']}">
        twoDOuterArray[${status.index}] = new Array(3);
    </c:forEach>

    <c:forEach var="mapEntry" varStatus="status" items="${data['cData']}">
    <c:forEach var="dataValue" varStatus="status2" items="${mapEntry.value}">
        var valueArray = new Array();           
        alueArray.push(${dataValue.value});
        valueArray.push("${mapEntry.key}");
        twoDOuterArray[${status2.index}][${status.index}]=valueArray;
    </c:forEach>
    //alert(twoDOuterArray[${status.index}].length);
    </c:forEach>



    data.push(twoDOuterArray);

    alert(twoDOuterArray);

    plot2b = $.jqplot('chart2', data, {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 },
            shadowAngle: 50,
            rendererOptions: {
                barDirection: 'horizontal'
            }
        },
        title:{
            text: "${title}",                    
            show: true,               
            textColor:"#fff",
        },
        axes: {
            yaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
            }
        },
        legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
    });


    );

</c:forEach>
});
```

It seems that format is correct but I don't understand where I am wrong or is this the correct way to create data. if anyone could help me to solve this that would be great.

edit:
how I can check that my array is created in the above required format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what your data looks like, I'd use Firebug (or your favorite browser's equivalent) to set a breakpoint on the call to jqplot. Then inspect the variable you want to check.

Also it seems jqplot should be using `twoDOuterArray` but you are passing it `data` which might be a problem.

One more thing: if you original data object contains more than one element, the outer `<c:forEach>` you have will result in jqplot overlaying new plots on the previously generated ones.

Instead of mixing the JSTL with the Javascript I would also suggest building your 2d array from wherever your other variables are set (for example: a controller). Then convert the object to JSON with a library like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and pass that to jqplot directly.